# How to get ID of disabled firebase user (during authentication)?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, authentication, firebase-authentication

If I disable a user from console user credentials will not be refreshed in one hour and user will be deauthenticated. Upon trying to log in, user will get the FirebaseException with the ErrorCode AuthError.UserDisabled.

Showing the user that his account is disabled is good, but I also want to show him his firebase account ID (which is a complex string with letters and numbers) for support inquiries. How can I get the user Id to show it to user when the account has been disabled? This is happening in Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the UID matching the credentials is not exposed in this error message, so you will have to look it up another way. The best I can think of is using the Admin SDK to [find the user by their email address](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.baseauth.md#baseauthgetuserbyemail).